# Function to paste text as a orgmode table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to have a function (that I can bind to a key) that pastes the current text in the clipboard as a formatted org table?

Also as a bonus (since this is used to create as ingredients table for a cookbook) it would be great to be able to define the columns in advance so that the amount|type|ingredients are nicely separated. For example take this list

```
3/4 cup milk
2 tablespoons white vinegar 
1 cup all-purpose flour
2 tablespoons white sugar
1 teaspoon baking powder
1/2 teaspoon baking soda
1/2 teaspoon salt
1 egg
2 tablespoons butter, melted
cooking spray
```

If I mark this as a region and issue `org-table-create-or-convert-from-region` this is the result

```
|     3/4 | cup         | milk        |         |      |        |     |       |         |
|       2 | tablespoons | white       | vinegar | (%or | better | yet | lemon | juice%) |
|       1 | cup         | all-purpose | flour   |      |        |     |       |         |
|       2 | tablespoons | white       | sugar   |      |        |     |       |         |
|       1 | teaspoon    | baking      | powder  |      |        |     |       |         |
|     1/2 | teaspoon    | baking      | soda    |      |        |     |       |         |
|     1/2 | teaspoon    | salt        |         |      |        |     |       |         |
|       1 | egg         |             |         |      |        |     |       |         |
|       2 | tablespoons | butter,     | melted  |      |        |     |       |         |
| cooking | spray       |             |         |      |        |     |       |         |
```

As you can see it got the amount (1/2) and the unit (cup) right yet the actual ingredients is cut into several columns.

I don't really know how to deal with this. Is there a more intelligent way of auto directing the conversion to split it the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something that basically parses your recipe. Here is one that seems to do what you want. You highlight the recipe ingredients and run it.

```
(defun recipe-to-org (start end)
  "Split an ingredient list to a table.
Column 1 is a the quantity, column two is the ingredient.
We split on spaces, then handle these cases:

1. first word starts with a number, and the number of words is two
  1 egg

2. The first word does not start with a number
  cooking spray

3. Everything else.
  2 tablespoons butter, melted
"
  (interactive "r")
  (let* ((lines (split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties start end) "\n"))
     tokens
     (table
      (mapconcat
       'identity (loop for line in lines
               do
               (setq tokens (split-string line))
               collect
               (cond
                ;; 1 egg
                ((and (string-match "^[0-9]" (car tokens))
                  (= 2 (length tokens)))
                 (format "| %s | %s |" (nth 0 tokens) (nth 1 tokens)))
                ;; line not starting with a number
                ((not (string-match "^[0-9]" (car tokens)))
                 (format "| | %s |" line))
                ;; everything else.
                (t
                 (format
                  "| %s | %s"
                  (concat (nth 0 tokens) " " (nth 1 tokens))
                  (mapconcat 'identity (cddr tokens) " ")))))
       "\n")))

    (setf (buffer-substring start end) table)
    (org-table-align)))
```

This converts your recipe ingredients to:

```
| 3/4 cup       | milk              |
| 2 tablespoons | white vinegar     |
| 1 cup         | all-purpose flour |
| 2 tablespoons | white sugar       |
| 1 teaspoon    | baking powder     |
| 1/2 teaspoon  | baking soda       |
| 1/2 teaspoon  | salt              |
| 1             | egg               |
| 2 tablespoons | butter, melted    |
|               | cooking spray     |
```

Comment: thx @John. i seem to be getting an error `and: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` when i try to run the function on a highlighted section

Comment: It sounds like you highlighted an empty line, either before or after the region. It should work if you just highlight the region from a start of a line to the end of a line.

Comment: perfect, sorry for the late response